# Название типа боевого построения

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называются такие фигуры (квадраты), типы построения марширующего войска? Каким словом обозначить одну единицу (один квадрат), чтобы описывать ее действия в отдельности от действий других единиц?

Comment: Одно каре, два каре 
 http://elgar.16mb.com/2012/11/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/

Answer (score 2):

Такое построение называется "каре".

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)